# How to count report pages in pre-rendered MorphX report?

Tags: report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

We are trying to force a morphX report to be an even number of pages in length (so our auto-folding machine can handle the workload properly) and have been unsuccessful in using `element.pagesTotal()` to do so.

How have others gotten a page count for per-entity reports at the element level?

(this is dynamics ax 2009)

Comment: yes, sorry my first post on here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but `pagesTotal` is a "magic" function that delivers the result after the report has finished, which is too late for you to emit a `newPage`.

You will have to count yourself. Luckily X++ is quite good at it!

Declare your counter in `classDeclaration`:

```
 Counter pc;
```

Increment your counter in a page header `execute` section:

```
 pc++;
```

In fetch add your `newPage` after super() (or on break of customer number):

```
boolean fetch()
{
    boolean ret = super();
    if (pc mod 2 == 1)
        element.newPage();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: From memory in AX2009 you may need to add an empty programmable section to the report and execute that after element.NewPage(), otherwise the report may not create the new page as there is nothing to show on it

Comment: Thanks Jan, that is essentially what we ended up doing. I hadn't heard of the Counter data type but will look more into that for future reference. We didn't have to add an empty programmable section...

Comment: It is an `int` extended datatype, you might as well write int.