# Axapta 2009 Report PagesTotal

Tags: report, axapta, morph-x

Axapta 2009 Report PagesTotal() method, current page / total pages, can you show  how?

Like (1/9 or 2/7) [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q660d.png)

Comment: Please provide more details in your questions, it is hard to answer them without knowing more about the context, requirements and what you have tried so far. Also take a look at the help section of stack overflow, there are several guides on how to ask good questions.

Comment: HI,

Is it possible to reset page total in AX report?

For example, I need to print a report for multiple vouchers. Voucher A will display page 1 of 3, page 2 of 3 and page 3 of 3, voucher B display page 1 of 2, page 2 of 2 and so on..

Can this be done?

I can reset the element.page() but not element.PagesTotal().

 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use two report controls, the first with the [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa640026(v=ax.50).aspx) method, the second with the [PagesTotal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa846407(v=ax.50).aspx) method.

See the report `tutorial_Reset` for an example of its use.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14590986/4509) and [this question on how to reset counters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10704009/4509).